# How to distribute aggregations on each columns when groupingby in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

**I got the following csv:**

```
region,area,distributor,salesrep,sales,invoice_count                                                                                                                       
Central,Butterworth,HIN MARKETING,TLS,500,25                                                                                                                                 
Central,Butterworth,HIN MARKETING,TLS,500,25                                                                                                                                 
Central,Butterworth,HIN MARKETING,OSE,500,25                                                                                                                                 
Central,Butterworth,HIN MARKETING,OSE,500,25                                                                                                                                 
East,JB,LEI WAH,NF05,500,25                                                                                                                                                  
East,JB,LEI WAH,NF05,500,25                                                                                                                                                  
East,JB,LEI WAH,NF06,500,25                                                                                                                                                  
East,JB,LEI WAH,NF06,500,25
```

**If I groupby like this:** df.groupby(['region','area','distributor','salesrep']).sum().unstack(['distributor','salesrep']).to_string()

**I got the following result.**

```
                             sales                       invoice_count                    
distributor          HIN MARKETING        LEI WAH        HIN MARKETING       LEI WAH      
salesrep                       OSE   TLS     NF05  NF06            OSE  TLS     NF05  NF06
region  area                                                                              
Central Butterworth           1000  1000      NaN   NaN             50   50      NaN   NaN
East    JB                     NaN   NaN     1000  1000            NaN  NaN       50    50
```

Is there a way of instead of having a separate sales and invoice_count groupings of the aggregations have the aggregation distributed on each individual columns.

**Something like this.**

```
distributor          HIN MARKETING      HIN MARKETING   HIN MARKETING   HIN MARKETING   LEI WAH        LEI WAH   LEI WAH        LEI WAH
salesrep                       OSE                OSE             TLS             TLS      NF05           NF05      NF06           NF06
                             sales      invoice_count           sales   invoice_count     sales  invoice_count     sales  invoice_count
region  area                                                                              
Central Butterworth           1000                 50            1000              50       NaN            Nan       NaN            NaN
East    JB                     NaN                Nan             NaN             Nan      1000             50      1000             50
```

I tried solving it by iterating through the columns and getting each aggregation then creating a new dataframe out of it. But there must be a more straight forward way of doing this in pandas that I might be missing out.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
In [27]: df.groupby(['region','area','distributor','salesrep']).sum().T
Out[27]: 
region               Central           East      
area             Butterworth             JB      
distributor    HIN MARKETING        LEI WAH      
salesrep                 OSE   TLS     NF05  NF06
sales                   1000  1000     1000  1000
invoice_count             50    50       50    50
```

Comment: Not exactly but thanks for your time and introducing me T attribute. I labeled my desired result **"Something like this"** in my question.